# Renaming files in a directory to specific prefix

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, rename

I have 54 files in a directory who have the names from *file00_Layer-53.png* to *file52_Layer-1.png*. I would like to rename all these files to **file01.png** to **file53.png**

I know I have to use the rename command, but I am having difficulty using it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the rename command:

```
c=0 rename 's/.*/sprintf("file%02d.png", ++$ENV{c})/e' *.png
```

Use the -n flag if you want to do a test first:

```
c=0 rename -n 's/.*/sprintf("file%02d.png", ++$ENV{c})/e' *.png
```

The way this works is, for each argument, it executes the perl `s///` expression, and performs the rename from the original to the replaced string. In the replacement string I use `sprintf` to format the name, where I use the environment variable `c` as the counter from 1.

Or you can use a simple loop counter:

```
j=1; for i in *.png; do mv "$i" file"$j".png; let j=j+1; done
```

If you want to pad with 0 for 2-digit numbers:

```
j=1; for i in *.png; do mv "$i" file$(printf %02d $j).png; let j=j+1; done
```

Comment: That seemed to have work. But there is an underscore between file. For example **file26_Layer-27.png** It renamed all the files but still has the Layer-* number part on all of them. I would like to renamed the complete file name.

Comment: @Randolphg I don't understand. Can you please give an exact example of FROM and TO?

Comment: I have 54 files in a directory who have the names from *file00_Layer-53.png* to *file52_Layer-1.png*. I would like to rename all these files to **file01.png** to **file53.png**